# Wordpress terrible image resolution

Tags: wordpress

Would anyone be able to help me fix the terrible resolution on the front page my team's webiste [my team's webiste](http://firstfusion364.com) Would there be any code that I can add to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, When inspecting the image it says that the natural image is 720px by 720px, but it has been stretched out to 1170px by 1170px. Which causes the image quality to go down.

As you can see when viewing the original image: http://www.firstfusion364.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/IMG_0959.jpg

You will have to upload the original image with a higher resolution, that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked out your website and could see that when I reduce the size of my browser, the quality of the image improved.  I am by no means an expert on image related matters but have you tried altering the image dimensions, to the desired size, prior to uploading?  I can see that the image dimensions are 720px by 720px.  Try altering your image (ideally prior to uploading) to the following dimensions: 1170px by 1170px.  See if this helps!  If you are unsure of how to do this, just let me know and I will provide a step by step list for you.

Let me know how you get on with this.

**Update**

Ideally, you will want to delete the image via FTP, ensuring that all size variants of the image are also removed.  Deleting an image, by the WordPress Dashboard only, does not always remove said size variants.  Consequently, your page may still load the 'wrong sized' image, despite you uploaded the modified image.